NP-hardness of a string transformation problem with k templates
Given strings $x$ and $y$, a template length $l$, and a maximum number of different templates $k$, the task is to determine if it's possible to convert $x$ into $y$ using no more than $k$ different templates, each of exactly length $l$. For example, if $x = AAA$, $y = ABC$, $l = 2$, and $k = 2$, the answer would be YES because it's feasible to achieve the transformation with just two different templates of length 2. For example $AB$ to get $ABA$ and then $BC$ to get the desired $ABC$.
The goal would be to prove that this problem is NP-hard by reducing a known problem to this problem.
I've tried many problems but never successfully.
Thanks for your help!
